# Getting VM on ESXi to use COM ports on local (thin?) client

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-esxi, serial

Setup:

- WinXP VM on ESXi v4.1 infrastructure system, accessible via vSphere thick client and RDP
- WinXP client (i.e. my laptop) with a device connected to the serial port

How do I get the VM to talk to the device connected to my local system?

Already tried:
 - Ensuring that all boxes are checked in the "Local Resources" tab on RDC client, trying it and running it as is (it did not appear to 'just work')

Comment: What makes you think you can?

Answer (score 0):

Serial Ports over RDP requires RDP v7.0 (mstsc.exe 6.1 or newer). It is natively available in Win7and Server 2008R2, and [WinXP's client can be upgraded](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084).

Comment: Thanks for the info! So that takes care of the client. What about the host WinXP that I'm connecting to?